# How can I extract a subset of a dictionary into another one in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to filter out some dictionary pairs I do not need for further processing. Check this sample code out:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var source = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

    source.Add("number", 1);
    source.Add("string1", "One");
    source.Add("string2", "Two");
    source.Add("string3", "Three");

    var onlyStrings = source.Where(s => s.Key != "number").ToDictionary(s => s.Key);
}
```

In this case, onlyStrings is a `Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, object>>`

but I want onlyStrings to have the following pairs (a subset of the source dictionary):

- Key: "string1", Value: "One"
- Key: "string2", Value: "Two"
- Key: "string3", Value: "Three"

What is the best way to get such result?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is an overload to the ToDictionary method that also allows for an elementSelector delegate:

```
var onlyStrings = source.Where(s => s.Key != "number")
                        .ToDictionary(dict => dict.Key, dict => dict.Value);
```